# Background image resize

Tags: html, css, xhtml, frontend

I have a html which includes body background. the imagae size is w: 400 and h: 300. and also   i have set the this html window / browser size to 400 x 300. when i maximize the window the background image also should fit to the screen. how could i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Read through the techniques here, look at the demos, and pick the one you find most suitable:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: What doesn't work? Which of the techniques are you trying to use?